# React Native onPress event delay

Tags: javascript, android, ios, performance, react-native

I develop an application with React Native and everything is ok, but there is one problem. when I touch TouchableOpacity or TouchableWithoutFeedback in Android there is some second delay for trigger onPress event and I don't know why. anyone can help me???

Comment: this could be related to debug js remotely. Is it faster if you don't disable the option?

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff I thinking when generate signed APK with ./gradlew assembleRelease command, It disables js debugging automatically! no?

Comment: Yep. That was a suggestion. But it could also be code related then If you have an issue on a release build.

Comment: Yeah, I have that problem in release and I don't know what to do

Comment: If its one particular component you could post some code...

Comment: It's not a special component.
I removed all console.log and console.warn so it's much faster

Answer (score 1):

I removed all Console message and replace TouchableOpacity with TouchableWithoutFeedback and disable navigation transition animation  so it's much faster